# Could MergeDocuments be failing silently when merging multiple large files?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In our organisation, we send documents out for comment and then later combine them such that all of the comments can be first viewed together in a single document, then selectively accepted.  Often, these documents are quite large (>1MB) and it is not uncommon to merge sets of 5 to 10 documents together.  Often the merge of a set of large documents fails, meaning the first two documents of a group have been merged, but the third and subsequent documents are missing from the end result.

After some experimentation, we have come to "believe" that the problem lies in the code which loops through the set of files to be merged.

```
Private Sub standardMerge(files() As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim file0 As String: file0 = files(0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(files)
        DoEvents
        Word.Documents.Open fileName:=files(i), ReadOnly:=False, addtorecentfiles:=False

        Application.MergeDocuments _
            OriginalDocument:=Documents(files(i)), RevisedDocument:=Documents(file0), _
            Destination:=wdCompareDestinationRevised, _
            Granularity:=wdGranularityCharLevel, _
            CompareFormatting:=True, CompareCaseChanges:=True, CompareWhitespace:=True, _
            CompareTables:=True, CompareHeaders:=True, CompareFootnotes:=True, _
            CompareTextboxes:=True, CompareFields:=True, CompareComments:=True, _
            FormatFrom:=wdMergeFormatFromRevised, CompareMoves:=True

        DoEvents
        snooze 5
        Documents(files(i)).Close False
        DoEvents
    Next i
End Sub
```

As the documents are large, we imagine that Word fires off processes to perform the individual merges. One process starts before the previous one is fully complete, consequently subsequent merges fail silently.

We added a "snooze" function to delay Word between iterations.  This seems to have helped, but this solution is really just kicking the can down the road.  It is unclear whether this is really the problem or really a solution.  The snooze function is the usual call to the Windows API.

```
Public Sub snooze(arg As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long: a = arg * 1000
    Word.Application.StatusBar = "Snooze for " & arg & " seconds"
    For i = 0 To a / 250
        Sleep 250
    Next i
End Sub
```

Is this at least a plausible explanation of the merge silent failure problem?

Is there a better solution to this problem which does not rely on blindly sticking in a delay?

Comment: If, as a test, you attempt such a merge manually, as a user, is it successful? (To determine whether it's a problem with the docs or just when doing it with code.)

Comment: Manual merge works fine.  The only point of doing this was to eliminate the sheer tedium of doing the merge for several files.